# Excel 2013: Generate list meeting all requirements

Tags: excel, dynamically-generated, office-2013, excel-2013, vba

I need to create a spreadsheet that randomly draws a winner that has correctly answered all questions.

---

### Verifying Answer

I've added a Column **'Correct'** which verifies the answer was properly answered. It returns *QuestionID* if correct and *'Incorrect'* if FALSE.

I have another table with the answers to verify the database results.

- 9747 | Wrong | Correct | Wrong
- 9748 | Correct | Wrong | Wrong
- 9749 | Wrong | Wrong | Correct
- 9751 | Correct | Wrong | Wrong
- 9752 | Wrong | Wrong | Correct
- 9753 | Wrong | Wrong | Correct

---

### Pull Possible Winners

I need to get all PersonID that have properly answered all the questions. If they incorrectly answer a question they are disqualified. Also if they failed to answer a question they are disqualified.

[image: TableWithData]

Comment: Why not just filter your table?

Comment: Does every person answers only one QuestionID? If it is not so, are they disqualified from one question round or from all questions?

Comment: @DanielCook Filter just removes Incorrect Answers. I still need to check each PersonID and see if it has 6 questions answered correctly.

Comment: @JüriRuut Each person Answers all 6 QuestionIDs. If they have answered < 6 then they are disqualified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow the layout of visible in the sheet image and compiled my own sheet:
http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Answers_to_quiz_correct_wrong.xls  Blocks with additions are marked with light green, error situations with yellow.

Defined C1:C200 as PersonList.

All formulae are in row 2, if not stated otherwise.

Column J: correct answers selected by

```
=IF(AND(E2="Right",F2="Right",G2="Right"),B2,"")
```

Column L: compiled unique list of participants by array formula (Shift-Control-Enter, curled brackets added by Excel itself, not by a user):

```
  {=INDEX(PersonList,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($L$1:L1,PersonList),0))}
```

Column M: list of answers for the first question found (the first means position in a table):

```
=MATCH($L2,$C$2:$C$2000,0)+1
```

Column N: list of answers for other questions, copied further to columns O:R

```
=MATCH($L2,INDIRECT("$C"&M2+1&":$C$2000"),0)+M2
```

Column S: correct answer sought by a row number in column M. If the question wwas answered properly, question code will be displayed. The formula is copied to columns T:X.

```
=(INDEX($J$1:$J$200,M2))
```

Column Y: Winners and DQ. Array formula again:

```
{=IF(SUM(IF(S2:X2="",1,0))=0,"Winner","DQ")}
```

Now AutoFilter can be applied.